# What is this succulent called? Got it from japan

Tags: identification, succulents

i would love to get a help on identifying my lovely succulents that i got from japan.
Would love to understand how to take care of this little fella more!

Like how to make it nice and green, keep it hydrated and healthy.. and when to move it to a bigger pot and such..
Appreciate any info as a help!!

[image: help me to identify this succulent from japan]

Comment: A photo showing more detail would help. At first I thought it was a succulent hybrid, but after zooming in I think it's an etiolated Mammillaria vetula gracilis or something. It's very stretched to the point of not having discernible tubercles.

Comment: Your main problem will be watering.  This plant stores its own water, too much water and it will rot.  DO NOT water this plant until that pot and plant feel very light.  A better pot would be half the depth of this pot and the same diameter.  Are you using potting soil I hope, have you put anything else in this pot other than potting soil?  Have you ever fertilized?  With balanced fertilizer?  Your plant is very shallow rooted. Water only when dry and just moisten the top inch of soil and wait until the soil is dry to water again.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is a member of the only genus of cactus that exists in the old world... Rhipsalis some of the species... it is possibly `Rhipsalis baccifera`, there are a lot of species, most are epiphytic, and have small red or white fruit... I am not a cactus expert, but the one that I had was probably either `Rhipsalis baccifera` or `Rhipsalis pilocarpa`, and it required a lot of water for a cactus, I guess it was from a fairly wet forest.

As with pretty much any cactus if you watch carefully you can see it shrink as it dries out... so it is actually pretty apparent when needs water if you look at it regularly... but I would still let it dry out between waterings and pot it in a cactus mix, never let it sit in water.

Comment: What is "the old world"?

Comment: The old world is europe/asia/africa... new world is north and south america... not sure where australia fits in...  just eurocentric terms used by biologist